# Item{"LookUpField"} giving error

Tags: 2007

I am trying to get field value but keep getting using code,

```
if(listItem["myLookUpColumnName"] != null)
```

Exception

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

What can i do to avoid this exception even though field name is alright.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the internal name of the field and not the display name.

Comment: it is internal name of field

Answer (score 1):

Check the List schema and see what name it has for the corresponding column which you are referring to in your code.

Comment: already did, its same

Answer (score 0):

Lookup field is a field which links a child class to a parent class, it is an association kind, which allows a list item to reference another item from another list. However, reading and writing to a lookup field is different from a normal field. We need to use the class SPFieldLookupValue to achieve this.

Ex:

```
SPFieldLookupValue spv = new SPFieldLookupValue(listItem["LOOKUP_NAME"].ToString());
ddl.SelectedValue = spv.LookupValue.ToString(); // this line gets the value from the lookup field and I'm assigning it to a dropdown, you can change it according to your wish.
```

Use the Internal name of the Lookup field to access it.

Comment: thankyou but its a multiple value lookup

Comment: then try using `// Get the predecessors. 
string rawvalue = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Predecessors].ToString(); 

SPFieldLookupValueCollection values = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(rawvalue);`

Comment: what's Predecessors ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the field name you're referring to doesn't exist in the item, even though it exists in the list.

With normal columns this can happen if the field isn't listed in the ViewsFields. With lookups this can also happen if the lookup field was added after the list item.

Here is my answer on a similar question, with more details: [ArgumentException when trying to access SPListItem value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15827/argumentexception-when-trying-to-access-splistitem-value/17824#17824)

Comment: unfortunately your answer didn't helped, thanks tho

Comment: when i try to get SPFields of item, it does show the field i am trying to get value of

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I just ran into the same problem.

In my case I had created a lookup column as a *site column* (let's call it `LookupColumnA`) that uses `MyListA` as its source list. `LookupColumnA` was than added to `MyListB`. So nothing unusual here and everything worked fine. At one point though, I was forced to delete `MyListB`, which I did. After creating `MyListB` again, I was facing the error as you described it.

While debugging I found that the field was present in my `MyListB` object, but the value of the field was not. My conclusion was than that there could be some kind of orphaned field reference of the original lookup field of my first `MyListB` (which I deleted) which was than reapplied to my newly created `MyListB` (just my theory!).

Nevertheless **here is was worked for me:**

- Creating a new column (let's call it `LookupColumnA1`)
- Adding this `LookupColumnA1` to `MyListB`
- (Copying data from `LookupColumnA` to `LookupColumnA1`)
- Deleting `LookupColumnA`